# Как разбить введенные пользователем числа пробелами?

Tags: c#, консоль

Допустим, пользователь вводит в консоль ряд некоторых чисел. Как сделать, чтобы ему нужно было вводить их через пробел, и каждое из чисел считывалось как отдельное? Например я ввожу: "6 0 73 15", нажимаю enter, и далее мне нужно с этим набором чисел произвести некоторые действия.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
var numbers = Console.ReadLine()
        .Split(new[] {" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(Int32.Parse);

foreach(var n in numbers)
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Давайте рассмотрим, что происходит:

`Console.ReadLine()` - считывает всю строку с пробелами, что ввел юзер

`.Split(new[] {" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` - разбивает считанную строку на несколько строк, используя пробел как сепаратор. То есть была строка `"45 67"`, стало 2 строки `"45"`, `"67"`

`.Select(Int32.Parse);` - конвертирует набор строк в набор чисел. То есть были 2 строки `"45"`, `"67"`, стало 2 числа `45`, `67`

В итоге в `numbers` будет находится объект - перечисление чисел, которые ввел пользователь. Дальше по коду я перечисляю этот объект, чтобы вывести в консоль.

```
foreach(var n in numbers)
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Comment: Да,всё вышло, а не могли бы Вы словами объяснить строчки кода?:)буду благодарна

Comment: @LolyPrincess обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Answer (score 2):

Можно и без Linq:

```
int[] numbers = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(), int.Parse);
```

Т.е. считываем строку с консоли `Console.ReadLine()`, потом методом `Split()` получаем из этой строки массив, при этом при отсутствии параметров в качестве разделителей будут приняты все пробельные символы.

Затем метод `Array.ConvertAll` применяет ко всем элементам входного массива функцию, переданную вторым параметром (`int.Parse`), таким образом, из массива строк получается массив int

Comment: Спасибо большое!!) очень помогли